# Sample testing automation code with iOS using Appium

Tags: ios, objective-c, automated-tests, appium

I want to learn about testing automation in iOS using Appium. However, I don't know where to start. I think that it would be easier to learn if there are sample test codes. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me for the asynch reply. You view sample code & project @ [here](https://github.com/appium/sample-code/)

Do checkout the sample App projects at [Cloud Monkey](https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-getting-started/install-and-run-demo-app)